# Analyzing time complexity (Poly log vs polynomial)

Tags: time-complexity

Say an algorithm runs at

[5n^3 + 8n^2(lg (n))^4]

Which is the first order term? Would it be the one with the poly log or the polynomial?

Comment: Which do you think is bigger, `n` or `(lg n)^4`?

Comment: I would think the (lg n)^4 is bigger, but aren't poly logs less weight than polynomials?

Comment: Look at `n / (log(n)^4)` for increasingly large values of `n`.

Comment: Ah I see, the n is a larger weight, but how can you tell this at first glance? Is this always the case for general poly log? Also would this function then be considered Theta(n^3)?

Answer (score 6):

For each two constants `a>0,b>0`, `log(n)^a` is in `o(n^b)` (Note small o notation here).

One way to prove this claim is examine what happens when we apply a monotomically increasing function on both sides: the log function.

```
log(log(n)^a)) = a* log(log(n))
log(n^b) = b * log(n)
```

Since we know we can ignore constants when it comes to asymptotic notations, we can see that the answer to "which is bigger" `log(n)^a` or `n^b`, is the same as "which is bigger": `log(log(n))` and `log(n)`. This answer is much more intuitive to answer.